# 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I am programming a little minesweeper game in python for my IT course in school.
Now i am getting the error "'int' object is not subscriptable" in line 58, a function which is generating the amount of mines next to the input square

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase

gameHasEnded = False
size = 0
mines = 0
PG = []
CT = []

#eine clear Funktion um die Konsole zu leeren bzw. einfach runter zu scrollen
def cls():
     print ("\n"*100)

#Funktion in der Sämtliche Dinge stehen sie zum Start nur einmal ausgeführt werden müssen
def start():
    global size
    size=(int(input("size")))
    global mines
    mines=(int(input("mines")))
    #spielfeld wird generiert
    global PG
    PG = [["#" for i in range(size)]for j in range(size)]
    global gridsize
    gridsize = len(PG)
    #Kontrollfeld wird generiert
    global CT
    CT =[["0" for i in range(size)]for j in range(size)]



#Funktion zum Auswählen einer Zufallskoordinate
def getrandomcellandsetmine(grid):
    global mines
    while mines > 0:
        Z1 = random.randint(0, gridsize - 1)
        Z2 = random.randint(0, gridsize - 1)
        #print(Z1)
        #print(Z2)
        if CT[Z1][Z2] != "X":
            CT[Z1][Z2]="X"
            mines=mines-1

def generateNeighborCount():
    global CT
    for x in range(0,size):
        for y in range(0,size):
            if CT[x][y] != "X":
                a = 0
                list = [(-1, -1),
                        (0, -1),
                        (1, -1),
                        (-1, 1),
                        (0, 1),
                        (1, 1),
                        (-1, 0),
                        (1, 0)]
                for l in list:
                    newx = (x)+l[0]
                    newy = (x)+l[1]
                    if (newx >= 0 and newx < size and newy >= 0 and newy < size):
                       if CT[newx][newy] == "X":
                            a += 1
                       if a > 0:
                          CT[x][y] = str(a)


#Funktion um die Nachbarn einer eingegebenen Koordinate zu ermitteln
def openPos(pos):
    if (pos[0] < 0 or pos[0] >= size or pos[1] < 0 or pos[1] >= size):
        return
     if PG[pos[0]][pos[1]] == CT[pos[0]][pos[1]]:
         print("test")
         return
    PG[pos[0]][pos[1]] = CT[pos[0]][pos[1]]
    if CT[pos[0]][pos[1]] == " ":
        list = [(-1, -1),
                (0, -1),
                (1, -1),
                (-1, 1),
                (0, 1),
                (1, 1),
                (-1, 0),
                (1, 0)]
        for l in list:
            openPos(((pos[0]+l[0]), (pos[1]+l[1])))
    elif CT[pos[0]][pos[1]] == "X":
       gameHasEnded = True

        for xo in CT:
            x=CT.index(xo)
            for yo in CT[x]:
                y = CT[x].index(yo)
                if CT[x][y] == "X":
                    PG[x][y] = CT[x][y]

#Input der Koordinate als Int./Ausgabe der Anzahl der Umgebenden minen als Int.
#funktion für den Userinput
def userinput():
    ui=(input("deine koordinate (x-y)"))
    uiList = ui.split("-")
    pos = (int(uiList[0])-1), (int(uiList[1])-1)


    openPos(pos)


#Funktion zum schönen und übersichtlichen darstellen
def showplayground (grid):
     horizontal = '   ' + (4 * gridsize * '-') + '-'
     # Fügt Buchstaben oben ein
     toplabel = '     '

    for i in ascii_lowercase[:gridsize]:
        toplabel = toplabel + i + '   '

    print(toplabel + '\n' + horizontal)

    # Fügt links Zahlen ein
    for idx, i in enumerate(grid):
        row = '{0:2} |'.format(idx + 1)

        for j in i:
            row = row + ' ' + j + ' |'

        print(row + '\n' + horizontal)

    print('')






start()

#for i in range(len(PG)):
    #print(PG[i])

#for i in range(len(CT)):
 #   print(CT[i])

#cls()


getrandomcellandsetmine(PG)
generateNeighborCount()
while not gameHasEnded:
    cls()
    showplayground(CT)
    userinput()
#for i in range(len(CT)):
#   print(CT[i])
print ("Du hast verloren")
```

Comment: How do we map line 58 to your posted code which has fewer than 58 lines? Also your indentation is incorrect

Comment: You shouldn't call your list `list`, since that is the name of the list type.

Comment: This code would not produce the error you describe at the line you are indicating.

Comment: what is `newx = x+l[0]` supposed to do?

Comment: its not my complete code,

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Now its the complete Code

Comment: Your code does not raise any error on Python 3.6.

Comment: Please try to get rid of all those `global` declarations. Use parameters and return values instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

You edited your question so as to post your entire code. Once I had corrected a few `IndetationError`s, your code worked without raising any error.

---

There are only two different subscriptions<sup>1</sup> in your code: to `CT`, and to `l`.

`l` is an element of `list`, which contains only tuples, that are subscriptable.

Therefore, if the error is effectively raised by the code you posted, it is raised by a subscription to `CT`.

The value to `CT` is not clear defined in the code you posted, so I cannot be sure that it is subscriptable. However, this is the only possible place in this piece of code that might raise a `TypeError` stating that `'int' object is not subscriptable`.

---

As a side note, please note that `list` should never be used as a variable name. It refers to the `list` class, and re-assigning it would override the `list` constructor. The same applies to `int`, `str`, `dict`, `set`, `float` and `tuple` (and probably other).

Besides, `CT` is not defined in your code. This bare piece of code would raise a `NameError`. You probably defined it before in the rest of your code, and Python tolerates that you call it from the inside of your function, but since you expect it to be a global variable, you should add `global CT` at the beginning of your function's body (though there are better practices).

---

<sup>1: A *subscription* is when you call the `[]` operator on an object. `l[1]` is a subscription to `l`.</sup>